# In K6 can we connect to a GRPC service without specifying port number?

Tags: grpc, k6

We have our GRPC services behind a gateway server, when I connect using BloomRPC I specify the hostname(without port) and enable TLS(Server Certificate option).

In K6 when I try to create a connection,

```
client.connect('<hostname>', {
       
    });
```

I am getting an error saying the port number is mandatory, So I tried giving the port as 443 but our proxy is not able to identify the requests because of which getting a response with status 12(UNIMPLEMENTED)

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Specifying the port should not break anything. What happens if you explicitly set the port in BloomRPC?

Comment: @knittl I don't want to pass port number to k6 script, our proxy service is not able to identify the requests when the port number is appended to the URL. The same is the case with BloomRPC as well.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the proxy service

Comment: yeah it was, got it handled in proxy service. thank you @kn